# Impossible to compile a generated siddhi extension

Tags: java, wso2, siddhi

I don't succeed to compile a generated Siddhi java extension project, here is what I did :

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP400/Writing+Custom+Siddhi+Extensions).

**1.** I executed the required maven archetype in order to generate the project sketelton

```
mvn archetype:generate
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.wso2.siddhi.extension.archetype
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=siddhi-archetype-execution
    -DgroupId=org.wso2.extension.siddhi.execution
    -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The name of the project : GetReferenceInformation

**2.** Then I ran a maven compile inside the new extension project folder generated

```
mvn compile
```

Result :

```
(...)
[INFO] Starting audit...
C:\dev\siddhi-execution-rfe\component\src\main\java\org\wso2\extension\siddhi\execution\rfe\aggregate\GetReferenceInformationAggregateFunction.java:123: error: La premiere ligne doit se terminer avec un point.
C:\dev\siddhi-execution-rfe\component\src\main\java\org\wso2\extension\siddhi\execution\rfe\aggregate\GetReferenceInformationAggregateFunction.java:136: error: La premiere ligne doit se terminer avec un point.
(...)
C:\dev\perso\siddhi-execution-rfe\component\src\test\java\org\wso2\extension\siddhi\execution\rfe\aggregate\TestCaseOfGetReferenceInformationAggregateFunction.java:3: error: Commentaire javadoc manquant.
C:\dev\perso\siddhi-execution-rfe\component\src\test\java\org\wso2\extension\siddhi\execution\rfe\window\TestCaseOfGetReferenceInformationWindow.java:3: error: Commentaire javadoc manquant.
Audit done.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] siddhi execution getReferenceInformation 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  4.462 s]
[INFO] Siddhi execution of getReferenceInformation 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT FAILURE [  0.907 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.411 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-16T13:14:27+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) on project siddhi-execution-rfe: Failed during checkstyle execution: There are 21 errors reported by Checkstyle 6.11.2 with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wso2/code-quality-tools/master/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml ruleset. -> [Help 1]
```

How strange is that ? The generated code doesn't pass it's own audit ?

How to deactivate the automatic Checkstyle (from a custom maven extension I believe) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can skip checkstyle validation by adding the following config in the pom,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I tested the above scenario that you have mentioned, however, the project compiles successfully. Note this was generated from archetypeVersion=1.0.2 which is the latest archetype for Siddhi 4x